# Where is the Source code of calculator apps in ubuntu?

Tags: application-development

Where is the source code of the calculator apps in ubuntu located?

How to edit the source code so that it is possible to add new features by writing some code.

Answer (score 6):

You can run this command in terminal

```
apt-get source gcalctool
```

The files will be placed in your /home directory

Comment: @sriram Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

The application is named `gcalctool` and is developed under GNOME.

It is hosted on GNOME Git. [Get the source code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gcalctool)

You can get the source code by using git and running the command

```
git clone git://git.gnome.org/gcalctool
```

which will get you the development version of the code.

and then you will find the folder name gcalctool which will contain the source code with the complete history

You can download the release from their [ftp site](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/gcalctool/) where the latest release at the moment is 6.6 - [Download the latest tarball](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/gcalctool/6.6/gcalctool-6.6.0.tar.xz)